# angular ui-select (group by) initial value always select last of the duplicates

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have problem with selecting initial value if there is a duplicate of object property id.

The foo bar example is: 
group favourite animals:

```
    {id:'1',text:'dog', group:'Favourite animals'},
    {id:'2',text:'parrot', group:'Favourite animals'},
    {id:'3',text:'cat', group:'Favourite animals'}
```

group all animals:

```
    {id:'1',text:'dog', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'2',text:'parrot', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'3',text:'cat', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'4',text:'fish', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'5',text:'turtle', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'6',text:'hamster', group:'All animals'}
```

The dog, parrot and cat is de facto duplicate, only by id (bind model)

The problem is, that ui-select select the last of them, if i set as initial value like this:

```
$scope.model = ['1'];
```

If i choose from dropdown, everything is ok than.

Is there any way to "tell" ui-select to choose the first of them?

Whole code (HTML, js) bellow or example codepen http://codepen.io/martin80cz/pen/qdwJMm

HTML:

```
   <div ng-app="app" class="container">
      <div ng-controller="select" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>ui-select (group by) initial value always last problem</h1>
          <ui-select theme="bootstrap" ng-model="model[0]">
            <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.text}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="value.id as value in options | filter: {text:$select.search}"
                               group-by="'group'">
                <div ng-bind-html="value.text | highlight: $select.search"></div>
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('app',['ui.select','ngSanitize'])
.controller('select',['$scope',function($scope){
    //initial value
  $scope.model = ['1'];
  //all options
  $scope.options = [
    //without group
    {id:'0', text:'Not chosen',group: undefined},
    //favourite animals
    {id:'1',text:'dog', group:'Favourite animals'},
    {id:'2',text:'parrot', group:'Favourite animals'},
    {id:'3',text:'cat', group:'Favourite animals'},
    //all animals
    {id:'1',text:'dog', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'2',text:'parrot', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'3',text:'cat', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'4',text:'fish', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'5',text:'turtle', group:'All animals'},
    {id:'6',text:'hamster', group:'All animals'},
    ]
}]);
```